# How to use ChatJoinRequestHandler for telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

This is how I initiate the app:

```
application = Application.builder().token(os.getenv(bot_token)).persistence(persistence).build()  
new_member_handler = ChatJoinRequestHandler(send_hello_message)
application.add_handler(new_member_handler)
application.run_polling()
```

All other handlers are working fine, but `ChatJoinRequestHandler` isn't.

send_hello_message func:

```
def send_hello_message(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    print('someone added')
    join_request = update.chat_join_request
    user = join_request.from_user

    try:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=user.id, text="Hello! Please reply to this message to continue.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error sending message: {e}")
```

Bot has all permissions in the channel, but it never starts send_hello_message function.

Can anybody help me with it please?